# Configurar ViewResolver con Spring4

Tags: java, excel, jsp, spring, apache-poi

Buenas a todos.

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con Spring4 y Maven en Java.

Y quiero añadir una opción de exportar los datos de una tabla a una hoja excel, usando Apache POI.

El problema es que no me reconoce bien el mapeo a la vista de exportar el excel.

He estado siguiendo generalmente los pasos indicados en el [siguiente enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37983946/abstractexcelview-is-deprecated-in-spring-based-application)

Aquí os dejo las siguientes clases de mi aplicación, por si me podéis echar una mano.

**TaskController.java** (controlador de la vista con la tabla que quiero expor

> private Collection tasksExcel = null;

```
/**
 * This method will list all tasks by a user.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/tasklist" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listTasks(ModelMap model) {
    int id = getPrincipalUser().getId();
    Collection<Task> tasks = taskService.findAllTasksFromUser(id);
    double tasksDuration = taskService.getTasksDuration(tasks);
    double remainingHours = taskService.getRemainingHours(getPrincipalUser().getMaxHrsWeek(), tasks);

    tasksExcel = tasks;

    model.addAttribute("tasks", tasks);
    model.addAttribute("tasksDuration", tasksDuration);
    model.addAttribute("remainingHours", remainingHours);
    model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
    return "task/tasklist";
}
// Acción de exportar a excel
@RequestMapping(value = {"/exportexcel" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView exportExcel(ModelMap model) {

    return new ModelAndView("excelView", "tasks", tasksExcel);
}
```

**tasklist.jsp** (vista que lista las tareas dadas por el controlador, ésta es la parte del botón para exportar a excel)

```
        <div class="well">
           <a href="<c:url value='/task/exportexcel' />" class="btn btn-success custom-width">Excel</a>
        </div>
```

**ExcelBuilder.java** (clase que se encarga de darle formato a la hoja excel)

```
public class ExcelBuilder extends AbstractXlsView{

protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model, Workbook workbook, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    // Nombre del archivo
    Date now = new Date();
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"tareas-"+now.toString()+".xls\"");

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Collection<Task> tasks = (Collection<Task>) model.get("tasks");

    // Creamos hoja de excel
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Tasks");

    // Creamos cabeceras de las columnas
    Row header = sheet.createRow(0);
    header.createCell(0).setCellValue("ID");
    header.createCell(1).setCellValue("Usuario");
    header.createCell(2).setCellValue("Tipo de tarea");
    header.createCell(3).setCellValue("Fecha");
    header.createCell(4).setCellValue("Duración");
    header.createCell(5).setCellValue("Última modificación");

    // Añadimos la información a las columnas
    int rowCount = 1;

    for (Task t : tasks){
        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(t.getDate());
        String lastModification = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(t.getLastModification());

        Row taskRow = sheet.createRow(rowCount++);
        taskRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(t.getId());
        taskRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(t.getUser().getName());
        taskRow.createCell(2).setCellValue(t.getType());
        taskRow.createCell(3).setCellValue(date);
        taskRow.createCell(4).setCellValue(t.getDuration());
        taskRow.createCell(5).setCellValue(lastModification);
    }

}
```

**AppConfig.java** (aquí es donde declaro las ViewResolver que usa la aplicación)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "incurridos")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

/**
 * Configure ViewResolvers to deliver preferred views.
 */
@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {

    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    viewResolver.setOrder(1);
    registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);

    ResourceBundleViewResolver resolver = new ResourceBundleViewResolver();
    resolver.setBasename("views");
    resolver.setOrder(0);
    registry.viewResolver(resolver);
}
```

**views.properties** (aquí indico dónde está la clase encargada de darle formato al excel)

```
excelView.(class)=util.AbstractXlsView
```

**Edito:** se me olvidó añadir el error que se me muestra al pulsar en el botón para exportar a excel.[image: Aquí la imagen]

Espero haber podido explicar bien mi situación, cualquier cosa que no quede clara estoy a vuestra disposición para aclararla.

¡Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda!

Comment: tu excel builder no es un servlet?, a lo mejor necesitas extender de httpServlet o implementar Servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo tengo una solución distinta que lo mismo te es más sencilla:

Mis métodos en el controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/export")
public void exportExcel(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    logger.info("Exporting");           
    export(generateData(),response,"datos.xls");
}

// sólo la firma del método es relevante aquí, para darle algo de
// sentido al código a continuación
private ArrayList<MisDatos> generateData() {...}

public void export( ArrayList<MisDatos> data, HttpServletResponse response, String fileName)
        throws IOException {

    byte[] excelFileByte = getExcelFileAsBinary(data);

    // generando el fichero con lo que tengo en data, fuera del
    // alcance de la pregunta. Asumamos que se guarda en la variable
    // excelFileByte correctamente.

    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    if (excelFileByte != null) {
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=30");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
        response.setContentLength(excelFileByte.length);
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        out.write(excelFileByte, 0, excelFileByte.length);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Antes que nada, muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta.
A simple vista parece bastante más simple, pero me surge ahora una duda, cómo genero el fichero devolviendo un byte[]? puesto que como yo lo había planteado, al recibir los datos, ya devolvía la hoja de excel creada.

Comment: Acabo de crear el método getExcelFileAsBinary(data) guiándome por aquí [Convertir de collection a bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758889/collection-of-objects-to-bytes-format-and-then-vice-versa-in-java) y consigo que genere el excel pero los datos no se muestran bien

Comment: Finalmente conseguí arreglarlo basándome en tu solución propuesta. ¡Muchísimas gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Sólo por dejarlo claro: el fichero xls lo genero usando [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/index.html) y luego lo serializo, usando un `ByteArrayOutputStream`, para poder enviarlo fácilmente.